# Export Libgdx Project to Android

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I want to test my libgdx project on different devices

I used this option in eclipse (Export Unsigned Application Package) to make an apk file which I install on my device but it says Application not Installed

In AndroidManifest file min version is 8 and target version is 20

My device version is 4.0.3

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to generate proper .apk file from your project are:

1. Right mouse button on your android project and choose **Export**
2. Choose **Export Android Application** -> next
   [image]
3. Make sure that in the text box there is same project as your android is named -> next
   [image]
4. Create your own keystore using your own password -> next
5. Fulfill the required 4 first inputs and at least one of others (for example first and last name) -> next
   [image]
6. Choose **destination** and finish

**Important** - make sure you can install application from untrusted sources - it should be in Android device settings, security settings or in application/developers settings (I'm not sure how it is in your Android version - I've got Lolipop and it is **unknown sources** in security options)

If it will install but not run then there probably is an issue with your **Build path configuration** but I hope it won't.